# Javascript - reduce to an object

Tags: javascript, reduce

Execute below code in chrome console - for the google page.

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input"))
                       .map(el => el.name?el.name:el.id)
```

I see this output.

[image]

I wanted to reduce this list to an object.

```
         .reduce((acc,el) => acc[el] = el.toUpperCase(), {});
```

I expected something like below...

```
            {
                "sclient":"SCLIENT",
                "site":"SITE",
                ...
            }
```

But it returns only the last element.

[image]

What is wrong with this reduce function?

Comment: The callback function needs to return `acc`.

Comment: Thanks @4castle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `acc[el] = el.toUpperCase()`, which will return the value for `el.toUpperCase()`. In other words, you're returning a new string every iteration. You need to return your accumulator (acc):

```
.reduce((acc,el) => {
   acc[el] = el.toUpperCase();
   return acc;
}, {});
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: `(acc,el) => (acc[el] = el.toUpperCase(), acc)` also works.

Comment: If it wouldn't be improper to upvote for an avatar, I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a huge fan of one-liners and browser support is the least of your concerns, you could use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (ES6).

```
.reduce( (acc,el) => Object.assign(acc, {[el]: el.toUpperCase()}), {});
```

`Object.assign` takes an object as the first argument, and return the very same object (strict equality).

Note the `[el]` as the object key - a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (ES6).